# Graphical debugger for bash

Tags: debugging, macos, bash, ide

Is it there any graphical debugger for bash on mac os x or linux? I mean something in the same fashion that the debugging mode of Visual Studio or Eclipse, where one can stop the program hover the mouse pointer over variables and get instantly values, modify them and go backwards and try modifications without the need to start the program fomr the beginning. I am talking about very long bash scripts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for debugging execute your script with:

```
bash -x <scriptname>
```

gui debugger:
http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: how can you use DDD with bashdb?

Answer (score 5):

Debugger for Bash version 3(Bourne again shell). Plugin for Eclipse. Will only work with shell script editor ShellEd.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/basheclipse/

Answer (score 4):

I have found the `vscode-bash-debug`
 extension (https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug) for the `visual studio code` editor (https://code.visualstudio.com/) very useful.

Comment: This is an excellent tool, and if you're ambitious enough, it can even be used on the Mac. Just build your own bash version 3 or 4 along with bashdb. One of the configuration entries allows you to explicitly specify the bash executable to use and the associated bashdb. The only tricky thing is avoiding using language features from versions 3 or 4 - the Mac's default bash is version 2.x, and will not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across a visual debugger, but bashdb works quite well for debugging. You can set breakpoints, continue, print variables etc..

https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashdb/

Install via your distro's repositories. There is a quick-start guide here:
http://www.rodericksmith.plus.com/outlines/manuals/bashdbOutline.html
(first chapter takes only half an hour to read/try).